# Модуль isodate, строка с промежутком времени, Python

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, что за модуль такой isodate, как его использовать для проверки строки с промежутком времени в формате 'PyYmMdDThHmMsS', где y, m, d, h, m, s – это количество лет, месяцев и т.д., на соответствие формату ISO 8601. Искал в сети хоть какую-нибудь внятную документацию по данному модулю, безуспешно. Необходимую библиотеку isodate установил в pycharm, а как работать с модулем без понятия. Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Никак, ваш формат не соответствует ISO 8601, и в принципе ISO 8601 - это про конкретные даты, а не про промежутки времени.